# Programs Not Receiving and Sending Alternatively

Tags: c++

Program seems to work, but can't figure out why its not running second part of code. For example, when I compile and execute msg2.cpp it prompts user to 'Enter some text'. When user inputs text msg1.cpp displays user input. The issue is msg1.cpp is not prompting user 'Enter some text'. Any suggestions on how I can receive and send message alternatively?

```css
//msg2.cpp
/* The sender program is very similar to msg1.cpp. In the main set up, delete the
 msg_to_receive declaration and replace it with buffer[BUFSIZ], remove the message
 queue delete and make the following changes to the running loop.
 We now have a call to msgsnd to send the entered text to the queue. */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 512

struct my_msg_st {
    long int my_msg_type;
    char some_text[MAX_TEXT];
};

int main()
{
    int running = 1;
    struct my_msg_st some_data;
    int msgid;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    long int msg_to_receive = 0;

    msgid = msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (msgid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgget failed with error: %d\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(running) {
        printf("Enter some text: ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        some_data.my_msg_type = 1;
        strcpy(some_data.some_text, buffer);

        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&some_data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (strncmp(buffer, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Then the messages are retrieved from the queue, until an end message is encountered.
 Lastly, the message queue is deleted. */

    while(running) {
        if (msgrcv(msgid, (void *)&some_data, BUFSIZ,
                   msg_to_receive, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error: %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("You wrote: %s", some_data.some_text);
        if (strncmp(some_data.some_text, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

    if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

```css
//msg1.cpp
/* Here's the receiver program. */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 512
//string UserInput(string);

struct my_msg_st {
    long int my_msg_type;
    char some_text[BUFSIZ];
    //char some_text[MAX_TEXT];
};

int main()
{
    int running = 1;
    int msgid;
    struct my_msg_st some_data;
    long int msg_to_receive = 0;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char some_text[MAX_TEXT];
    //string input;

/* First, we set up the message queue. */

    msgid = msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (msgid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgget failed with error: %d\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
/* Then the messages are retrieved from the queue, until an end message is encountered.
 Lastly, the message queue is deleted. */

    while(running) {
        if (msgrcv(msgid, (void *)&some_data, BUFSIZ,
                   msg_to_receive, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error: %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("You wrote: %s", some_data.some_text);
        if (strncmp(some_data.some_text, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

    if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Need to reset value, before entering second loop 
    // At this point, value enters loop, prompts user enter text
     while(running) {
        printf("Enter some text: ");
        for (int i = 1; i < running; i++){
        fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        some_data.my_msg_type = 1;
        strcpy(some_data.some_text, buffer);
        }
        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&some_data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (strncmp(buffer, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Does it display correctly if you add a newline after the prompt?

Comment: Scratch that...  Why don't you reset the value of `running` before hitting the second loop?

Comment: Is this the simplest example of the problem you can come up with?

Answer (score 0):

My .02 currency units are on this snippet from msg1.cpp:

```
if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You seem to delete the message queue here as soon as the 'end' message has been received.

(Also: `fprintf()` & friends in C++ program?)

Comment: If I comment out msgctl code snippet, program still runs. What can I do so it enters the second loop?

Comment: Actually, you should listen to what @paddy said 13 hours ago :-) That second loop in msg1.cpp never executes because `running` is still set to `0` (because that's why the _first_ loop terminated.)

Comment: Yes I know. Thats why I added a for loop, to change running from zero to one but its not working. For loop is located on line 66.

Comment: Line 64, I modified while(running = 1) and still not entering second loop! :)